# How to simplify array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have below array and I want to simplify array to add my logic to check product qty

The array is as below:-

```
$conditions = Array
    (
        [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
        [attribute] => 
        [operator] => 
        [value] => 1
        [is_value_processed] => 
        [aggregator] => all
        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found
                        [attribute] => 
                        [operator] => 
                        [value] => 1
                        [is_value_processed] => 
                        [aggregator] => all
                        [conditions] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product
                                        [attribute] => category_ids
                                        [operator] => ==
                                        [value] => 5
                                        [is_value_processed] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product
                                        [attribute] => category_factor
                                        [operator] => ==
                                        [value] => 13
                                        [is_value_processed] => 
                                    )                                                         

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Magently\CustomerRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Customer
                        [attribute] => product_qty
                        [operator] => >=
                        [value] => 99
                        [is_value_processed] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

I want to check `attribute` `operator` and `value` like below :

```
if(product_qty >= 99){
//do your stuff
}
```

Please help me to simplify this array to add my condition to check the product qty for some purpose.

Comment: Did your array is large and check elements or just want to access value ?

Comment: Yes my array is large and I want to check condition as explained

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understanding of your question.

You can use array indexes like this:

```
foreach($conditions['conditions'] as $condition){

    if($condition['attribute'] == 'product_qty' && $condition['value']  >= 99 ){
        //do your stuff
    }

}
```

this code checks when `attribute` is equal to `product_qty` and `value` of this item is more than equal 99. condition is true.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma did I correct understanding of what you want ?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @PurushotamSharma when `attribute` is equal to `product_qty` and `value` of this item is more than equal 99. condition is true. is it what you want or not ?

Comment: please view my condition example in my question

Comment: Any other clue for solution?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma this answer is what in your question and your example. think about array you have and this solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you better create a function that has the array as input.
it will do a for each like ttrasn mentioned:

```
foreach($conditions['conditions'] as $condition){

    if($condition['attribute'] == 'product_qty' && $condition['value']  >= 99 ){
        //do your stuff
    }

}
```

But ad if $condition is an array, recursive call the same function with that array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have easy way to perform a comparison with the operator stored in a value, so you need to write the function yourself. A simple `switch` can do the job :

```
function compareValue($variable, $operator, $value){
    switch($operator)
    {
        case '==' : return $variable == $value ; break ;
        case '>=' : return $variable >= $value ; break ;
        /* add all possibilities here */
        default : throw new RuntimeException("Undefined operator '$operator'");
    }
}
```

To evaluate you whole conditions, you can use recursion :

- if it is a comparaison to a value, use the function written above
- if it is an aggregate, evaluate all the childs and define the rule of the aggregate :

Here is a skeleton :

```
function checkConditions($product, $condition){
    if($condition['attribute'] !== false and $condition['operator'] !== false)
    {
        // simple condition 
        $variableToCheck = $product[ $condition['attribute'] ] ; // maybe use your API to query this value
        $operator = $condition['operator'] ;
        $valueToCompare = $condition['value'] ;
        return compareValue($variableToCheck, $operator, $valueToCompare);
    }
    else
    {
        // composite condition 
        if( $condition['aggregator'] == 'all' )
        {
            // check for each child condition
            foreach($condition['conditions'] as $childCondition)
            {
                $childConditionReturn = checkConditions($product, $childCondition);
                if($childConditionReturn === false)
                {
                    // we found a child condition that is not satisfied, the whole 'all' aggregator is false
                    return false ;
                }
            }

            // all childs were evaluated to true, whole 'all' aggregator is true
            return true ;
        }
        else // handle other aggregator types here
        {

        }
    }
}
```